# Which user IP addresses can moderators view?

Tags: support, moderators, privacy, pii

Moderators may view user IP addresses. E.g., moderators can [view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234713/178179) the user's last known IP address, when  viewing a deleted user.

Which other user IP addresses can moderators view? E.g., can they view the IP of the user when visiting SE (if so, can they view only the last IP, or the entire list of IPs used), when posting a question/answer/comment, when casting a vote?

Comment: I don't know if this sort of information will be able to be revealed because of how moderators will sometimes use it to track sock puppeteers and other abusive user behavior.

Comment: Why do you want / need to know, except curiosity?

Comment: [Live Overflow video](https://youtu.be/MS7WRuzNYDc?t=143) with some loose relevance here.

Comment: It's not a joke. The TL;DR is that carrier-grade NAT results in many users/devices sharing an IP address with other users/devices.

Comment: And depending on your ISP, your IP can change, you could have multiple IPs, I swap between ISPs ...

Comment: Regardless of what _moderators_ can see, most web servers keep an access of all IP addresses for each HTTP request. I have no idea if SE or their CDN keeps those logs, but if they do, I imagine only the server administrators would have access.

Answer (score 15):

The specifics of what PII moderators can access is generally restricted. If it's public what moderators can view, it would make it easier to circumvent the sockpuppet and fraud detection tools that moderators have access to.

Comment: I see your point. It's both reassuring and annoying of course.

Answer (score 14):

In general, mods do not have access to information on a per-vote level, the mod tools usually provide aggregated information. The general idea is that we have enough data to detect patterns, but not be able to e.g. attribute individual votes to specific users. There is also no expiry of data, so all data collected is kept forever.

I don't think there would be any harm in providing more details on which PII mods can access. I think this is a reasonable thing to ask from a privacy perspective. But this is really something you have to take up with SE directly, I don't think we mods can decide which details to reveal here.

Comment: Thanks, "aggregated information" aggregated per user (e.g. "this user cast 5 votes from IP X,  2 votes from IP Y, etc.), per post (e.g. "this post received 5 votes from IP X,  2 votes from IP Y, etc.), something else?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt per post would be pretty much the same as per vote, that is not information mods can see (but CMs can see more than we).

Answer (score 10):

As others have already said, information about exactly what capabilities moderators have is restricted, in order to limit users' ability to game the system (although I personally believe that is security through obscurity, but I don't make the policies).

If your concern is more about your own personal privacy, it is generally a good idea to *assume* that all information that *can* be collected, *is* collected—by any website you visit, not just Stack Exchange. Therefore, the privacy-conscious should assume that the operator of the website can see not only the IPs of all accesses, but also all browser headers sent to the server and even [TCP fingerprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting).

On Stack Exchange, moderators can't actually see all of this information. And even if they could, they are restricted by [the Moderator Agreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) to using the information they are provided strictly for moderation-related purposes. It's highly unlikely that a moderator would abuse that access. If they did, there would be serious consequences, such as their removal as a moderator due to violating the Moderator Agreement. Moderators take the privacy of PII access *very* seriously.

<sub>(Note that this answer is just common sense and is based on my general knowledge of how the Internet works, *not* based on any information that I know as a direct result of being an elected moderator on a Stack Exchange site.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Never been a mod.

There is a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352707/how-long-should-se-store-ip-addresses-of-users#comment1182749_353747) (10K only) under a deleted answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352707/282094) and it's known from elsewhere (no source) that a hash is available; and the IP list is available but raises a staff flag if accessed.

> "Every moderator or employee with moderator powers can see a list of every IP address a user ever accessed the site from.".

Moderators can't see who voted for what, but staff "easily" can.

Less "easy" (minor digging) is that obviously all information is available to staff, as it is on any other website (to the administrators).

"Viewing an entire list" would be no more difficult than writing down (or scraping) the IP address on a regular basis.

Since IP addresses can be hidden by VPN, Tor or public Wi-Fi they really have a limited value; it's the information that you haven't asked about which is most useful, and knowledge of is restricted.